# Why is Typography.Capitals parameter ignored?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have applied `SmallCaps` as shown below, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on in the browser or in a design window.

```
<TextBlock Text="Text Here !" Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps"/>
```

Why is `Typography.Capitals` parameter ignored? Are there any settings that need to be enabled for this ?

Comment: "As follows" ? Don't see anything :)

Comment: What font are you using? Also, please accept some answers if you can.

Comment: Same here. I tried "portable user interface" and various other fonts. All Typography.* properties appear to be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
It seems that for these properties to work, the font used must support them. Silverlight can not perform magic with the font, it can only work with the features built into the font itself. And it seems that there are some differences between different versions of Windows, which made this even more confusing. I have tried this on Windows 7 and 8 using the following fonts:
Gabriola, Georgia, Verdana, Arial, Comic Sans MS, Calibri, Segoe UI, Portable User Interface

On both Win7 and 8 the only properties that ever worked were SmallCaps and AllSmallCaps. None of the other settings made any difference whatsoever, neither on Win7 or Win8. On Windows 8 these two properties worked for all the fonts listed above. On Windows 7 the only fonts where they *did* work were Calibri and Gabriola. I then started looking into the versions of the fonts installed on the two different machines. It turns out they are different. For example, on my Win7 machine both Verdana and Segoe UI is of version 5.05. On the Win8 machine Verdana is version 5.31 and Segoe UI is version 5.28.

So I think this is why we get different results on different machines. It has nothing to do with Silverlight, but with the versions of the fonts installed on the client machine. The version of Verdana installed on Win7 has no support for SmallCaps and AllSmallCaps, but the version that comes with Win8 *does* have that support.
**END UPDATE**

I am definitely seeing a difference with SmallCaps and AllSmallCaps. The rest of the values don't seem to do anything. It could depend on the FontFamily used I suppose. Any way, the following code renders like the screen shot below.

```
<ContentControl FontSize="18"
                FontFamily="Segoe UI">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Writing Some Text Here in the Text Block. AllPetiteCaps"
                    Typography.Capitals="AllPetiteCaps"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Writing Some Text Here in the Text Block. AllSmallCaps"
                    Typography.Capitals="AllSmallCaps"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Writing Some Text Here in the Text Block. Normal"
                    Typography.Capitals="Normal"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Writing Some Text Here in the Text Block. PetiteCaps"
                    Typography.Capitals="PetiteCaps"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Writing Some Text Here in the Text Block. SmallCaps"
                    Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Writing Some Text Here in the Text Block. Titling"
                    Typography.Capitals="Titling"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Writing Some Text Here in the Text Block. Unicase"
                    Typography.Capitals="Unicase"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentControl>
```

[image: Typography Examples]

Comment: The same code is workin fine on the production server. but in development I am not able to see the same effect.

Comment: That is very strange. Silverlight is client-side only, this code should not be affected at all by anything on the server side. Are you sure that your browser is not caching the xap file when you run the code on your dev machine?

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund I'm getting the same effect as user221919. I copy-pasted your xaml in a newly created project, I don't get your results. All lines look the same. Very weird. My guess is that it has something to do with the fonts installed on the machine, or something related.

Comment: If you don't have Segoe UI installed it will fall back to the default font, which is called Portable User Interface. That is in fact a composite font which will use other fonts depending on what you have installed on your machine. What if you try specifying other fonts in the FontFamily attribute? I am getting the same results as in the screen shot with Verdana, Calibri and Comic Sans MS. That is, only AllSmallCaps and SmallCaps make a difference. With Arial however, Unicase also made a difference. It was really ugly though. :)

Comment: @John: I just saw in your other comment that you have already tried other fonts. That is strange. What OS are you on? Also, which version of Silverlight are you using? I am using SL 5, since the original question was tagged with that.

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund Windows 7, Silverlight 5, VS2012. So that should be pretty normal. I recall that I used to manage to have small caps some time ago on the same machine with the same installation when I first tested sl5, but then didn't use that feature for a while. That was VS2010 though, and a lot of other stuff got installed since.

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund It's especially strange that we get different results for fonts like Verdana, which are, according to Blend, built into the Silverlight plugin.

Comment: @John: I am on Windows 8. I just tried it on my other machine which is Win7, and you are right. I never would have guessed that Win8/Win7 could make a difference. Especially since some of the fonts are embedded in the plugin as you pointed out. The only font I can get it working with on Win7 is Calibri. Try that and see what results you get.

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund I missed your updates at the time you posted them. Thanks for the research, looks like this solves the mystery. There is one strange thing left: I remember I did try this shortly after SL5 came out on a win7 machine and it did work. I can't believe I used Calibri by accident, as it's not the default. Since I don't have the example project any longer, there's no way for me to research into it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much difference there is between WPF and Silverlight on this, but apparently for WPF the font has to be an OpenType font. According to [wpf.2000things.com](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/03/28/259-setting-typography-properties-for-text-rendered-with-an-opentype-font/):

> WPF includes a Typography class, which allows setting various attached properties for textual elements.  These properties only affect text that is rendered using an OpenType font.

And in [Programming WPF, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596510374.do):

> WPF supports both TrueType and OpenType fonts. OpenType fonts often contain
>   many alternates to the basic set of character shapes in order to support advanced
>   typographical functionality. If you are using a low-level text-handling feature such as
>   GlyphRun, you can use these alternates directly, referring to them by glyph index. But
>   if you are using the higher-level elements, such as TextBlock or the FlowDocument
>   viewers, these can locate and use the appropriate glyphs for you. You can control
>   which character shapes are used with the attached properties defined by the
>   Typography class.